# System of equations involving inner product and annihilation operator

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

Consider the $(2q+1)\times(2q+1)$ ladder operator
$$L=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots& \vdots&\cdots & \ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots &1\\
0&0&0&\cdots &0 \end{matrix}\right)$$
acting on $\mathbb{C}^{2q+1}$ . Given a vector  $c\in\mathbb{C}^{2q+1}\quad$ with $\langle c,c \rangle<1$,     find $d\in\mathbb{C}^{2q+1}\quad$ such that $\langle d,L^k\,d\rangle=-\langle c,L^k\,c\rangle$ for all $k=1,\cdots,2q$, where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product. Moreover, $\langle c,c \rangle+\langle d,d \rangle=1$.

I need to solve this problem for $d$ or at least find the conditions over $c$ such that it has a solution, but I don't even know where to start or to try finding something helpful.

Comment: I just realized that the normalization condition $\langle c,c,\rangle+\langle d,d,\rangle=1$ is not essential as I can normalize the solution in the end.